# Apache Age installation issue on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: postgresql, apache-age

**Installation of Apache-Age**

I'm trying to install Apache Age on my Ubuntu 20.04 server following the official documentation, but I'm facing an issue.

I have installed all the prerequisites, including Python 3.6+, PostgreSQL 10+, and Apache Arrow 3.0+, as mentioned in the documentation. However, when I try to install Apache Age using pip, I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement apache-age (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for apache-age
```

I'm not sure what's causing this error, as I have followed all the steps mentioned in the documentation. Can anyone suggest a solution for this problem?

Additional information:

I'm using Python 3.8.5.
I have already installed Apache Arrow using the command sudo apt install -y libarrow-dev.
I have also installed psycopg2 using pip.
I'm using pip version 20.0.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to install Apache AGE to use with Python, you need first to install Apache AGE following the steps in the [documentation](https://age.apache.org/age-manual/master/intro/setup.html) and then follow the instructions to [install the python driver](https://github.com/apache/age/tree/master/drivers/python) according to your Apache AGE version.

The PostgreSQL versions supported are 11, 12, and 13 so far. Make sure you installed both `postgresql` **and** `postgresql-server-dev` or `libpq-dev`.

The easiest way to install Apache AGE is from the source code. Here is an example to install Python driver for PostgreSQL 13 with Apache AGE 1.3.0:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3-dev libpq-dev
git clone https://github.com/apache/age.git
cd age/drivers/python
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Install Apache AGE from the code.
Install Python driver for PostgreSQL 13 with Apache AGE 1.3.0

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3-dev libpq-dev
git clone https://github.com/apache/age.git
cd age/drivers/python
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You should adopt a different procedure to setup Apache AGE and Python on your system.

I believe you have installed postgresql on your system. Next install Apache AGE, but be careful of the version you are trying to install. Make sure it's compatible with PostgreSQL version that you have installed.

Here's a tutorial for setting up Apache AGE:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0-qMwpDh0CA&ab_channel=%EB%B9%84%ED%8A%B8%EB%82%98%EC%9D%B8Bitnine

After successfully installing Apache AGE, now you have to install Python driver for Apache AGE to use Python with AGE.

Also make sure to check the paths of dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

For every language, there is driver to be configured and installed.
On [Apache AGE Documentation](https://age.apache.org/age-manual/master/intro/setup.html#getting-age), there are procedures to install pythoin driver.

Answer (score 0):

First try this command

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt install build-essential
```

after this Install postgres from source code:

```
wget https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/source/v11.18/postgresql-11.18.tar.gz && tar -xvf postgresql-11.18.tar.gz && rm -f postgresql-11.18.tar.gz
```

this will download postgres 11.18 but if you want anyother version then replace 11.18 with your desired version but make sure apache only support 11-12-13 postgres.

and follow this blog for complete postgres and age installation

[Installation of Apache age and PostgreSQL from source in linux](https://dev.to/talhahahae/installation-of-apache-age-and-postgresql-from-source-in-linux-part-1-gka)

Now for python :
1: Go to Age dir

```
cd age
```

2: now move to driver dir
cd driver
3: cd python

cd pyhton
and run

```
pip install requirment.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error says that your postgresql version may not be ompatible with your apache age version a few key things you should be lookimg is that age is official supported for postgresql version 11 and 12. I recommend you change your postgresql version to 11.18

```
wget https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/source/v11.18/postgresql-11.18.tar.gz && tar -xvf postgresql-11.18.tar.gz && rm -f postgresql-11.18.tar.gz
```

and for age and age viewer clone them from their repos

```
git clone https://github.com/apache/age.git
```

for age viewer use
git clone https://github.com/apache/age-viewer.git
make sure you have node version 14.16.0 for age viewer

Answer (score 0):

Installing Apache Age does not require Python only if you have to use the driver..

Steps are to first install age which requires postgres and other dependencies which you can find [here](https://age.apache.org/age-manual/master/intro/setup.html). Then you can also follow the docs to install the extension. Then to use the Python driver, cd into the python driver directory `drivers/python` you might also need to install Python and some other dependencies, you can follow the docs [here](https://github.com/apache/age/tree/master/drivers/python).

Answer (score 0):

**Update using these commands:**

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt install build-essential
```

Follow this blog for complete postgres and age installation:
Installation of Apache age and PostgreSQL from source in linux

For python :

1. Go to Age dir

```
cd age
```

2. move to driver dir:

```
cd driver 
cd python
```

3. then run

```
pip install requirment.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the latest version of pip installed. You mentioned that you have pip version 20.0.2, But for safe side run the following command:

```bash
pip install --upgrade pip
```

then install apache age using the following command:

```bash
pip install apache-age or pip install apache-age --extra-index-url https://dist.apache.org/repos/dist/dev/incubator/age/
```

Answer (score 0):

Run this command first:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt install build-essential
```

Then use this command for installing version 12 of PostgreSQL:

```
sudo apt install postgresql-server-dev-12
```